# Does a recruiter sees if I have ignored his InMail before

Tags: linkedin

This is kind of the extension of [Should I answer spontaneous messages from recruiters on LinkedIn?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153269/should-i-answer-spontaneous-messages-from-recruiters-on-linkedin)

I get quite a lot of InMail, when I am bored I am answering them in the spirit of the above question, but I have been quite busy and have skipped some of them.
If I am not interested at all, I am also tempted to write "Don't contact me again about $TECHNOLOGYSTACKS_I_DONT_WANT_TO_WORK_WITH"

I am interested in how the recruiter interface works.
Does the LinkedIn recruiter interface allow a recruiter to (de)select people that have been messaged previously when sending an InMail or is it more like "Send Message to All $KEYWORD-Developers in town"?

Comment: Just keep a polite but firm rejection template and use that ref https://blog.staffingadvisors.com/2014/11/20/decline-recruiters-outreach-politely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://www.linkedin.com/help/recruiter/answer/a412220?trk=hc-hp-suggestedArticles) from LinkedIn's help center possibly provides the answer you're looking for.

Recruiter accounts have access to some features like Talent Pool and Pipeline, which are different from search results. Think about them as a mailing list.

The recruiter can send messages using the Talent Pool mailing list instead of sending to search results. How the recruiters *maintain* their mailing list, however, is another entire different matter. A recruiter may remove you from their Talent Pool(s) due to non-responsiveness, or after you send feedback that you're not interested, or not at all, it's up to them, really.